# jQuery in external javascript file in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, intellisense

How to use jQuery in external javascript file in ASP.NET?

This is my code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/Javascript/Javascript.js" runat="server"></script>
    <script src="~/Javascript/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
```

But in `Javascript.js` file, I can't use jQuery selector `$()`.
When I use it doesn't work.

**Javascript.js**:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  alert('Hello'); 
});
```

This code doesn't work. Also IntelliSense doesn't work in Javascript.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include jQuery before Javascript.js

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/Javascript/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Javascript/Javascript.js" runat="server"></script>
</head>
```

You said you have these errors in your developer console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) localhost:46316/~/Javascript/Javascript.js 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) localhost:46316/~/Javascript/jquery-2.1.1.js 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

You can fix these by setting the paths to your files correctly:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="/Javascript/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/Javascript/Javascript.js" runat="server"></script>
</head>
```

Make IntelliSense work by putting this line of code to Javascript.js (as you realized yourself):

```
/// <reference path="jquery-2.1.1.js" />
```

Read the documentation of IntelliSense features and reference directives in here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx#Features

Comment: For ex, this code doesn't work. Also intellisense doesn't work
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('Hello');
});

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console of your developer tools (F12)?

Comment: Yes, there are errors, but I don't thik there must be error. I have used jquery in external javascript file in DreamVeawer but it doesn't in ASP.NET

Comment: Could you paste in the error you have there? Are you sure you have the relative paths to those files set correctly? You can drag&drop the files to <head> directly from Solution Explorer.

Comment: These are Chrome errors:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:46316/~/Javascript/Javascript.js

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:46316/~/Javascript/jquery-2.1.1.js

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: I dragged & dropped the files to head from Solution explorer. Path is correct

Comment: Which Visual Studio version are you using?

Comment: The problem is this: /// <reference path="jquery-2.1.1.js" />
this line must be included in external javascript file

Comment: @user3585369 that's a solution to another problem. with or without that line you can use the jquery selector.

Comment: @user3585369 Please mark this as the correct answer if you already solved the problem.

Comment: You could have given the code instead of explaining in simple English. Sorry, but I have given one down vote to you.

Comment: @Ashok kumar errm what?